# How to make a http post request in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, postman

I want to make a request to a device to start generating data and then to stop it. My computer is connected by Wi-Fi to a gateway.

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGWJ8xD2W6k and it is working for the http that is there, but when I writte mine is not working at all. I verify that the device is working with Postman.

Here is the MainActivity class of my code:

```
package com.example.test4;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mButtonResultStart;
private Button mButtonResultStop;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void Start(View view) {


    mButtonResultStart = findViewById(R.id.button_start);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    String url = "http://172.31.0.1/mm/ws/ecg/start/00:12:F3:1F:26:5E";

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                final String myResponse = response.body().string();

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mButtonResultStart.setText(myResponse);
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: \\ did you tried retrofit2 ?

Comment: you should use retrofit for that. check it out from the GitHub

Comment: use retrofit2 check this one https://medium.com/cr8resume/make-your-hand-dirty-with-retrofit-2-a-type-safe-http-client-for-android-and-java-c546f88b3a51